# I can't print a double value in the following code?

Tags: c++, double, cout

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

double distance(double, double);

int main ()
{
    double rate, time, distanceValue;

    cout << fixed << showpoint << setprecision(1);

    cout << "Enter rate" << endl;
    cin >> rate;

    cout << "Enter time" << endl;
    cin >> time;

    distanceValue = distance(rate, time);

    cout << "The distance is " << distanceValue << endl;
}

double distance (double num1, double num2)
{
    return num1 * num2;
}
```

when I try to compile it I see a long list of errors I don't what's wrong here! also if I change the method from double to int value it works well!! why??

the following error:

*> C:\Users\kifcaliph\Desktop\starting

> out with c++\Chapter6>cl 06_012.cpp
>   06_012 Microsoft (R) 32-bit C/C++
>   Optimizing Compiler Version
>   16.00.30319.01 for 80x86 Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights
>   reserved.
>
> cl : Command line warning D9024 :
>   unrecognized source file type
>   '06_012', object file assumed
>   06_012.cpp C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio
>   10.0\VC\INCLUDE\xlocale(323) : warning C4530: C++ exception handler used, 
>   but unwind semantics are not enabled.
>   Specify /EHsc C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio
>   10.0\VC\INCLUDE\xutility(373) : error C2825: '_Iter': must be a class or
>   namespace when followed by '::'
>           06_012.cpp(20) : see reference to class template instantiation
>   'std::iterator_traits<_Iter>' being
>   compiled
>           with
>           [
>               _Iter=double
>           ] C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio
>   10.0\VC\INCLUDE\xutility(373) : error C2039: 'iterator_category' : is not  a
>   member of '`global namespace''
>   C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft
>   Visual Studio
>   10.0\VC\INCLUDE\xutility(373) : error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' b
>   efore identifier 'iterator_category'
>   C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft
>   Visual Studio
>   10.0\VC\INCLUDE\xutility(373) : error C2602: 'std::iterator_traits<_Iter>
>   ::iterator_category' is not a member
>   of a base class of
>   'std::iterator_traits<_Iter>'
>           with
>           [
>               _Iter=double
>           ]
>           C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio
>   10.0\VC\INCLUDE\xutility(373) : see declaration of 'std::iterator
>   _traits<_Iter>::iterator_category'
>           with
>           [
>               _Iter=double
>           ] C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio
>   10.0\VC\INCLUDE\xutility(373) : error C2868: 'std::iterator_traits<_Iter>
>   ::iterator_category' : illegal syntax
>   for using-declaration; expected
>   qualified-name
>           with
>           [
>               _Iter=double
>           ] C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio
>   10.0\VC\INCLUDE\xutility(374) : error C2825: '_Iter': must be a class or
>   namespace when followed by '::'
>   C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft
>   Visual Studio
>   10.0\VC\INCLUDE\xutility(374) : error C2039: 'value_type' : is not a memb er
>   of '`global namespace'' C:\Program
>   Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio
>   10.0\VC\INCLUDE\xutility(374) : error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' b
>   efore identifier 'value_type'
>   C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft
>   Visual Studio
>   10.0\VC\INCLUDE\xutility(374) : error C2602: 'std::iterator_traits<_Iter>
>   ::value_type' is not a member of a
>   base class of
>   'std::iterator_traits<_Iter>'
>           with
>           [
>               _Iter=double
>           ]
>           C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio
>   10.0\VC\INCLUDE\xutility(374) : see declaration of 'std::iterator
>   _traits<_Iter>::value_type'
>           with
>           [
>               _Iter=double
>           ] C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio
>   10.0\VC\INCLUDE\xutility(374) : error C2868: 'std::iterator_traits<_Iter>
>   ::value_type' : illegal syntax for
>   using-declaration; expected
>   qualified-name
>           with
>           [
>               _Iter=double
>           ] C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio
>   10.0\VC\INCLUDE\xutility(375) : error C2825: '_Iter': must be a class or
>   namespace when followed by '::'
>   C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft
>   Visual Studio
>   10.0\VC\INCLUDE\xutility(375) : error C2039: 'difference_type' : is not a 
>   member of '`global namespace''
>   C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft
>   Visual Studio
>   10.0\VC\INCLUDE\xutility(375) : error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' b
>   efore identifier 'difference_type'
>   C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft
>   Visual Studio
>   10.0\VC\INCLUDE\xutility(375) : error C2602: 'std::iterator_traits<_Iter>
>   ::difference_type' is not a member of
>   a base class of
>   'std::iterator_traits<_Iter>'
>           with
>           [
>               _Iter=double
>           ]
>           C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio
>   10.0\VC\INCLUDE\xutility(375) : see declaration of 'std::iterator
>   _traits<_Iter>::difference_type'
>           with
>           [
>               _Iter=double
>           ] C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio
>   10.0\VC\INCLUDE\xutility(375) : error C2868: 'std::iterator_traits<_Iter>
>   ::difference_type' : illegal syntax
>   for using-declaration; expected
>   qualified-name
>           with
>           [
>               _Iter=double
>           ] C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio
>   10.0\VC\INCLUDE\xutility(377) : error C2825: '_Iter': must be a class or
>   namespace when followed by '::'
>   C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft
>   Visual Studio
>   10.0\VC\INCLUDE\xutility(377) : error C2039: 'pointer' : is not a member of
>   '`global namespace'' C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio
>   10.0\VC\INCLUDE\xutility(377) : error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' b
>   efore identifier 'pointer' C:\Program
>   Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio
>   10.0\VC\INCLUDE\xutility(377) : error C2602: 'std::iterator_traits<_Iter>
>   ::pointer' is not a member of a base
>   class of 'std::iterator_traits<_Iter>'
>           with
>           [
>               _Iter=double
>           ]
>           C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio
>   10.0\VC\INCLUDE\xutility(377) : see declaration of 'std::iterator
>   _traits<_Iter>::pointer'
>           with
>           [
>               _Iter=double
>           ] C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio
>   10.0\VC\INCLUDE\xutility(377) : error C2868: 'std::iterator_traits<_Iter>
>   ::pointer' : illegal syntax for
>   using-declaration; expected
>   qualified-name
>           with
>           [
>               _Iter=double
>           ] C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio
>   10.0\VC\INCLUDE\xutility(378) : error C2825: '_Iter': must be a class or
>   namespace when followed by '::'
>   C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft
>   Visual Studio
>   10.0\VC\INCLUDE\xutility(378) : error C2039: 'reference' : is not a membe r
>   of '`global namespace'' C:\Program
>   Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio
>   10.0\VC\INCLUDE\xutility(378) : error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' b
>   efore identifier 'reference'
>   C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft
>   Visual Studio
>   10.0\VC\INCLUDE\xutility(378) : error C2602: 'std::iterator_traits<_Iter>
>   ::reference' is not a member of a base
>   class of 'std::iterator_traits<_Iter>'
>           with
>           [
>               _Iter=double
>           ]
>           C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio
>   10.0\VC\INCLUDE\xutility(378) : see declaration of 'std::iterator
>   _traits<_Iter>::reference'
>           with
>           [
>               _Iter=double
>           ] C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio
>   10.0\VC\INCLUDE\xutility(378) : error C2868: 'std::iterator_traits<_Iter>
>   ::reference' : illegal syntax for
>   using-declaration; expected
>   qualified-name
>           with
>           [
>               _Iter=double
>           ]
>
> C:\Users\kifcaliph\Desktop\starting
>   out with c++\Chapter6>*

Comment: Show us error messages, copy-and-paste _exact_ code you had trouble compiling so we can replicate your problem reliably, and actually put some effort into _reading_ the error messages you receive so that maybe you can work out your own problems. Adding exclamation points to emphasize your distress is also a little annoying.

Comment: Though you might want to cut down the error message a little bit, or format it better. as posted, it makes your post appear to be mostly garbage. Two and a half screenfuls of dense letters and symbols is a bit much.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm *guessing* (since you didn't bother to actually show us the errors in question) that there's an ambiguity error between `std::distance` and `::distance` that's coming into play because of your using directive. Fully qualify `::distance` to force your function to be called, or get rid of the using directive and either fully qualify everything or add a using declaration for each of the symbols inside namespace `std` that you intend to use.

Also, you misspelled `distanceValue` as `distancValue` in the last line of `main`.

Comment: i'm not so sure that't the problem, at least in visual studio when you declare some function or variable outside namespaces it becomes the default one and no error is generated.

Comment: That misspelling suggests that this isn't a copy-and-paste of the actual code, and thus may not actually be representative of his code.

Comment: @Gajet : I tested both the OP's code and my proposed fixes in VC++ 2010.

Comment: after rechecking it you was right, it seemed for this specific code, there are some error due to ambiguity. and just changing `distanceValue = distance(rate, time);` to `distanceValue = ::distance(rate, time);` fixed that problem. at the time i put my first comment I only tried declaring `cout` for the second time.

Answer (score 5):

You are seeing an unfortunate side effect of `using namespace std;`. There is a function called [`std::distance`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/std/iterator/distance/); since you used `using namespace std;` it takes precedence over your own `distance` function.

The solution is to not use `using namespace std;`, and instead reference `std::cout`, `std::setprecision`, etc individually. You can also import specific identifiers from `std`:

```
using std::cout;
using std::setprecision;
using std::fixed;
using std::showpoint;
using std::cin;
using std::endl;
```

Or you can continue using `using namespace std;`, but explicitly request your own `distance` with `::distance` - this requests distance from the empty namespace specifically (not recommended; if anything is added to `std` this could break again).

Also, `distancValue` is a typo.

Answer (score 0):

It'll be ambiguity between `std::distance` and your `::distance` - either fully qualify the call, or dont include the whole of the `std` namespace.

Answer (score 0):

The error is that you wrote:

```
cout << "The distance is " << distancValue << endl;
```

instead of:

```
cout << "The distance is " << distanceValue << endl;
```

You see, there is a little 'a' in distance that you missed, fix it and it will work well.

And be careful next time :)